# Storing data from flash, best method?

Tags: php, xml, flash

What is the best way to store data gathered from a flash file, and load it into another flash file? Would xml or php work? and could it be instantaneous?
Here is a diagram of what i am trying to do...

http://img204.imageshack.us/i/examplea.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is a data structure. PHP is a coding language.

It's really hard to say what's the best way to store this. It depends on the server you're using, the expected amount of traffic you're going to get, and how you need to display the data later on.

If you're storing to a file, I'd say JSON or XML are good candidates.

If you expect a high volume of traffic or you need to retrieve specific subsets of records among inputted data, I'd recommend going with a SQL database (MySQL being a popular candidate)

Comment: Perfect reponse, thank you. Its really for a resturant. I want just want the owner to easily customize their own menus, and take items on/off if need, as well as change prices. i think using xml would be perfect, thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of data return would depend on a number of factors, including type and amount of data, network conditions, and what you do with the data once it's in your program.